# the usage of 'so' in ' it does so very slowly''

Tags: word-usage

> The moon rotates itself but it does so very slowly.

In this sentence, I wanted to know the usage of *so*.
*So* means 'very' or 'rotates itself'?

Comment: A very short answer: you can think of "so" in this context as just meaning "that", or "that thing".

Comment: Nice question. These are things I don't think about as a native speaker. It's always good to learn what you take for granted.

Answer (score 3):

In you example, **so** refers to the subject of the sentence, the moon's rotation, it's a placeholder

> The moon rotates itself but it does **so** very slowly
>   *The moon itself rotates but its rotation is very slow*
>
> I think **so**
>   *this is what I think*
>
> If you say **so**
>   *if that is what you are really saying*
>
> If it wasn't **so**
>   *If it wasn't the way it is*

Comment: I might have paraphrased the original like this: _The moon itself rotates but it rotates very slowly._ The "does so" allows the writer to avoid the repeating the word _rotates_ two times so closely together in the same sentence. (Such repetition is not necessarily problematic, and it's certainly not a grammatical error, but it's nice to have a way to avoid that repetition if the writer wants to do so.)

Answer (score 2):

So is used as an adverb and doesn't refer to the subject of the sentence. It usually **refers back** to something **mentioned before**. It is not a [placeholder](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=definition%20of%20placeholder) as it has the following meanings defined in [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so).

> (1) That is the case: ‘Has somebody called an ambulance?’ ‘I believe
>   **so**’
>
> (2) The truth: I hear that you’re a writer—is that **so**?
>
> (3) Similarly; and also: times have changed and **so** have I
>
> (4) Expressing agreement: ‘There’s another one.’ ‘**So** there is.’

Example sentences above mean:

> (1) I believe somebody called an ambulance.
>
> (2) Is that true that you're a writer?
>
> (3) I have also changed as times have changed.
>
> (4) Yes, there is another one.

As you can see, the adverb **so** functions mainly to **avoid repetition** of a  word or words that were previously mentioned.

Your example sentence will be

> The moon rotates itself but it (the moon) **rotates itself** very slowly.